# ASP Menu NavigateUrl empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, navigateurl

I have a Menu control, which I fill with MainItems in code:-

```
  <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="1em" BorderColor="#CC6600" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ClientIDMode="AutoID" ForeColor="Black" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#FF9900" />
    <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Project Management" Value="Project Management">/asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Quality" Value="Quality"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Training" Value="Training"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Sales" Value="Sales"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Administration" Value="Administration"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Maintenance" Value="Maintenance"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    </asp:Menu></td>
```

The Child Items are then read from a SQL table:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
ThisGroup = rdr.GetInt16(0);
MenuItem homeMenuItem = new MenuItem();
MenuItem newSubMenuItem = new MenuItem();
ci.Text = (rdr.GetString(1));
ci.NavigateUrl = (rdr.GetString(2));
homeMenuItem = Menu1.Items[ThisGroup];
newSubMenuItem = new MenuItem(ci.Text, ci.NavigateUrl);
homeMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(newSubMenuItem);
}
```

Hovering over each menu item shows a completely unrelated URL - the same one for all items - so I debugged at the OnClick event:-

```
string testtext1;
string testtext2;
testtext1 = e.Item.Text;
testtext2 = e.Item.NavigateUrl;
```

It turns out that the e.Item.Text has the correct value, but all the NavigateUrl values are "".
Can anyone spot what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `MenuItem(String, String)` sets the `Text` and `Value` properties of the new `MenuItem`. You want the `Text` and `NavigateUrl` properties set.

Instead of

```
newSubMenuItem = new MenuItem(ci.Text, ci.NavigateUrl);
```

Try

```
newSubMenuItem = new MenuItem(c1.Text);
newSubMenuItem.NavigateUrl = ci.NavigateUrl;
```